# Boolean Not changing on Command Link?

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, commandlink

I've got a command link that runs a method on a wrapper class.
This method should cause the WrapperClass's "Selected" variable to become "True".
For some reason it doesn't appear to do so?

Wrapper Class:

```
public class ProductWrapper {
    public Product2 Product {get;set;}
    public String productDescription {get;set;}
    public Boolean Selected {get;set;}

    public void setProduct(Product2 prod){
        Product = prod;
        productDescription = prod.Description;
    }

    public void selectProduct(){
        if(Selected == false){
            Selected = true;
        }
        else{
            Selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Visualforce Snippet:

```
<apex:repeat var="p" value="{!productWrappers}">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="accordion-group">
                                <div class="accordion-heading">
                                    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse{!rowNum}">

                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    {!p.Product.Name}

                                    </a>
                                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!p.Selected}">
                                        <a class="label label-default label-as-badge pull-right">Selected</a>
                                    </apex:outputText>  
                                    <apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(p.Selected)}">
                                        <apex:commandLink styleClass="label label-default pull-right" value="Not Selected" action="{!p.selectProduct}"/>
                                    </apex:outputText>         
                                </div>
                                <div id="collapse{!rowNum}" class="accordion-body collapse">
                                    <div class="accordion-inner">
                                        {!p.productDescription}
                                    </div>
                                </div>        
                            </div>

                        </li>
```

Controller Snippet(What creates the Wrappers):

```
public ConveniencePricingExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    products = [SELECT Id, Name, Account_Relatable__c, RecordTypeName__c, Description, Order__c FROM Product2 WHERE Account_Relatable__c = true ORDER BY Order__c];
    productWrappers = getProductWrappers();
}

public List<ProductWrapper> getProductWrappers(){
    List<ProductWrapper> allProducts = new List<ProductWrapper>();
    for (Product2 p:products){
        ProductWrapper product = new ProductWrapper();
        product.setProduct(p);
        allProducts.add(product);
    }
    return allProducts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use **apex:commandLink's reRender attribute** Pls **assign default value** to  `Boolean Selected`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm

**Working sample code**

Wrapper class

```
public class ProductWrapper {
    public String productDescription {get;set;}
    public Boolean Selected {get;set;}

    public ProductWrapper(String str){
        productDescription = str;
        Selected = false;
    }

    public void selectProduct(){
        if(Selected == false){
            Selected = true;
        }
        else{
            Selected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="FirstPageCtrl" showHeader="true" >

    <apex:form id="frm">

       {!ProductWrappers}
      <apex:repeat var="p" value="{!ProductWrappers}">
          <apex:commandLink styleClass="label label-default pull-right" value="Not Selected" action="{!p.selectProduct}" rerender="frm" status="counterStatus"/>
        </apex:repeat>  
        <apex:actionStatus  startText=" (incrementing...)"
            stopText=" (done)" id="counterStatus"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class FirstPageCtrl {

    public List<ProductWrapper> getProductWrappers(){
    List<ProductWrapper> allProducts = new List<ProductWrapper>();

        ProductWrapper product = new ProductWrapper('1');
        ProductWrapper product1 = new ProductWrapper('2');
        allProducts.add(product);
        allProducts.add(product1);
    return allProducts;
   }
}
```